# How to integrate waf to mfc project

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, waf

I am a newbie in waf, I want to integrate waf to my mfc project, but I faced a problem when linking files that "libcmt.lib(wincrt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup"
It seems that some lib or dll are not linked, I have no idea how to fix it, here is my wscript.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

out = 'out'

def options( opt ):
    opt.load( 'compiler_c compiler_cxx' )

def configure( cfg ):
    cfg.load( 'compiler_c compiler_cxx' )
    cfg.define('UNICODE', 1 )

def build( bld ):
    bld(
        features='c cxx cxxprogram',
        source='MessageShow.cpp MessageShow.rc MessageShowDlg.cpp stdafx.cpp',
        linkflags=(
                   '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS',
                   '/DEBUG',
                   '/DYNAMICBASE',
                   '/OPT:REF',
                   '/MACHINE:X86',
                   '/ALLOWISOLATION:NO',
                   ),
        target='MessageShow'
        )
```

Thanks

Comment: Add '/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup', will solve this problem